# How to dynamically pass sql in query in Launch in context?

Tags: maximo

I need to have a button in custom Location app, upon clicking which will take me to workorder application list tab with all the workorders created on the assets of the particular location.

I am using launch in context.

I tried using WF, but the workorder is opening in main tab instead of List tab.
[Work flow used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw4TH.png)
[Interaction Node details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1vri.png)

after routing, wotrack is opening like "http://hostname/maximo/ui/?event=loadapp&value=wotrack&**additionalevent=changetab**&additionaleventvalue=List&**uniqueid=72**&uisessionid=35&_tt=6e2h84jnc2qpnu9tohvo04qpdp"

how it is fetching workorder with unique id 72?

Comment: You could just as well create a tab in the Location app to display the work orders. There are out of the box relationships between location and work order, so it'd be a matter of creating the table body in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think Launch in Context is the wrong tool. Launch in Context is used for launching the user from Maximo into some external website / application, using some data from Maximo to provide some context to that application.

Instead, it sounds to me like you should use a Workflow process with an Interaction Node. In the Interaction Node, you can specify the Application and tab to take the user to and the Relationship from the Main Object of the current app to use to find the record(s) that should be loaded in the destination app for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how to set up Launch in Context, but this web page on the URL parameters you can use should help on that part at least.

http://maximodev.blogspot.com/2012/04/maximo-urls.html

Specifically, the example using the SQL query is probably what you need, since you want to display the records (workorders) associated with the records (assets) associated with the record (location) you have. (The earlier outline of the article has the wrong URL values for the "Perform a query using a where clause" section, but the example near the bottom has the correct setup.)

```
http://localhost/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?event=loadapp&value=wotrack&additionalevent=sqlwhere&additionaleventvalue=status%20in%20('WAPPR')
```

I think if you give the Launch in Context the part of that URL after the hostname, it will try to load it as a page at the current, which would end up taking you to exactly where you want to be, regardless of the public hostname of the server.

```
maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?event=loadapp&value=wotrack&additionalevent=sqlwhere&additionaleventvalue=status%20in%20('WAPPR')
```